# Pillar of Spiritual Intelligence (SQ)

Tags: compassion, wisdom

What is Buddhism view on this?

**Spiritual Intelligence (SQ)**

SQ may be defined as: “The ability to behave with wisdom and compassion, while maintaining inner and outer peace, regardless of the situation.” Wisdom and compassion being the pillars of SQ.

1. Deeper understanding of one’s own world view, life purpose, value hierarchy and controlling personal ego to consider the higher self.
2. Self-mastery of one’s spiritual growth, living your purpose, values and vision, sustaining faith in and seeking guidance from a higher power.
3. Universal awareness of world view of others, limitations and power of human perception, awareness of spiritual laws and transcendental oneness
4. Social Mastery/Spiritual Presence: wise and effective mentor of spiritual principles; leadership change agent; making wise and compassionate decisions; and being aligned with the ebb and flow of life.

Does Buddhism agrees on this statement below or there are more pillars?

> Wisdom and compassion being the pillars of SQ.

[Source - TRUE LEADERSHIP - SQ+EQ+IQ+PQ = SUCCESS](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20141116173602-54252615-sq-eq-iq-pq-success/)

Answer (score 2):

The tenets laid out by those bullet points are largely ego driven.  For instance, "controlling personal ego to consider the higher self", "self-mastery of one’s spiritual growth", "living your purpose", "leadership change agent", etc. deal overtly with the establishment and growth of a personal self.  As such, they are directly antithetical to Buddhist practice.  The remaining points are ancillary.

Some Tibetan lama somewhere once said that when you go to buy rice, it comes in a paper bag.  You don't got there with the intention of buying the bag.  It just comes with the rice - which is what you are after.  No offense intended, but pretty much everything in your question is just a brown paper bag.  Wisdom and compassion are likewise important...but again.  Paper bag.  We don't set out seeking to develop these virtues, they appear as a result of insight.

"Seeing emptiness, he feels compassion." - graffiti at the former site of Nalanda University